# How to make dummy variables with comma separated valued columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I am working on data preprocessing for machine learning and faced a problem. 
Here is what I want to do.

table image:

[image: table image]

Table's type is pandas dataframe.

My current table is left one, and I want to transform my table to right one.

The number of movies and actors are not fixed.

---

EDIT : 
Data input

```
 df=pd.DataFrame({'name':['A','B','C'],'actors':['a,b','b,d','c,m']})
```

Expected output :

```
       a  b  c  d  m

A      1  1  0  0  0
B      0  1  0  1  0
C      0  0  1  0  1
```

Comment: Please add the data as text, not as an image. Preferably in such a way that it can be copy&pasted straight to Python. What did you try so far? What did not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ? (BTW , kaggle movie dataset, better using [`LabelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html))

PS: I did not add the column `name`, you can simply do `out['name']=df.name`

---

Option 1  `pd.crosstab`

```
df.actors=df.actors.str.split(',')
df1=df.set_index('name').actors.apply(pd.Series).stack()
pd.crosstab(df1.index.get_level_values(0),df1).rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None,1)


Out[246]: 
   a  b  c  d  m
A  1  1  0  0  0
B  0  1  0  1  0
C  0  0  1  0  1
```

---

Option 2
 `get_dummies`

```
pd.get_dummies(df.actors.str.split(',').apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)

Out[230]: 
   a  b  c  d  m
0  1  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1  0  1
```

---

Option 3 
`MultiLabelBinarizer`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
    pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df.actors.str.split(',')),columns=mlb.classes_,index=df.name).reset_index()
Out[238]: 
  name  a  b  c  d  m
0    A  1  1  0  0  0
1    B  0  1  0  1  0
2    C  0  0  1  0  1
```

---

***Data Input***

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'name':['A','B','C'],'actors':['a,b','b,d','c,m']})
```

Comment: I didn't know there was a function like `df.actors.str.split(',')`. It was really helpful. Also thank you very much for giving me many options!

Comment: @kdino Yw, nice day